# Will my familiar remember me when I re-summon it, or is it a new entity?

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars, character-death, summoning

Playing D&D 5e, and my Pact of the Chain warlock's quasit familiar, Jimmy Peanuts, has fallen at the hands of a lizardman and vanished upon hitting 0 hp.

I understand that I can cast Find Familiar again and summon a quasit familiar, but I'm not entirely sure if I'm re-summoning Jimmy Peanuts, or a 'fresh' quasit (for the sake of argument, we'll call him Joey Walnuts).

Will the quasit be the returning Jimmy Peanuts, with whatever memories the quasit-resembling-familiar-spirit with INT 7 is capable of forming and retaining, or a fresh Joey Walnuts, who has no prior experience with me or my party?

(I have read this Q&A, but this particular familiar-death nuance isn't discussed: [What happens when a familiar 'dies'?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49716/what-happens-when-a-familiar-dies))

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**The same creature reappears.**

Take a closer look at the [Find Familiar](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Find%20Familiar#content) spell, it includes this text:

> When the familiar drops to 0 hit points, it disappears, leaving behind no physical form. It reappears after you cast this spell again.

Note that it doesn't say you get a new familiar, it just says it reappears. The familiar you get, regardless of form, isn't necessarily the type of creature it appears to be. The spell also includes this text:

> If you cast this spell while you already have a familiar, you instead cause it to adopt a new form. Choose one of the forms from the above list. Your familiar transforms into the chosen creature.

Your familiar just takes the form you have specified. It generally won't be that creature although a quasit familiar could actually be a quasit originally since it is a fiend which is one of the possible sources for familiar spirits.